# Save html form field state

Tags: javascript, html, forms, search

Today I came up with something interesting at one of my projects. I have a search box with several fields(ex.: licence plate, date of buy, state) and some of them has an operator field. (ex.: >, <, =)
After I post my search and returns the result say it i want to change one of my operators but always changes to the first element of it. Is there anything that i can do to "save" the state of the fields?

I could do it with sessions but it is a fairly big form so it would be ugly.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

A small snippet for you using `localStorage`:

- I have timed as 5 seconds to take a backup of everything on the form.
- Loads the stuff from the `localStorage` once the page is loaded.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (typeof localStorage["name"] !== "undefined") {
      document.getElementById("name").value = localStorage["name"] ? localStorage["name"] : "";
      document.getElementById("pass").value = localStorage["pass"] ? localStorage["pass"] : "";
    }
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
    setInterval(function () {
      document.getElementById("saving").innerHTML = 'Saving...';
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("saving").innerHTML = '';
      }, 500);
      localStorage.setItem("name", document.getElementById("name").value);
      localStorage.setItem("pass", document.getElementById("pass").value);
    }, 5000);
  }
};
```

```css
strong {display: inline-block; width: 50px;}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <strong>Name:</strong> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br>
  <strong>Pass:</strong> <input type="password" name="password" id="pass" /><br>
  <span id="saving"></span>
</form>
```

**Note:** `localStorage` is a sandboxed feature in snippets. So doesn't work here. Check in JSBin: http://output.jsbin.com/bubukunoke

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with sessions at the end.

When I post the form I save all of the content into a session and in the View I check if it exists and if yes I set it to as the field value.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.